# Can I modify the type of an object in python

Tags: python, object, types

specifically I want to change a StringType to a NoneType. I know how to use int() and str()
to convert between IntType and StringType, but I can't find a similar solution for NoneType. Is there a simpler solution besides using built in functions like int and str?

Sorry that was very ambiguous, I have a program that enters the string 'print("check")' into the python shell and I need it converted to a function. I assumed that because functions have the type NoneType that simply converting the string to NoneType would make it usable. Any ideas?

eval() works perfectly for my purposes Cairnarvon, thanks!

Comment: what is the usecase ?

Comment: How could you convert a variable to be `NoneType`? There is only one `None`- it's not like "hello" converted to `None` would be different than "goodbye" converted to `None`.

Comment: Are you looking to convert the string `"None"` to `None`?  Have a look at `ast.literal_eval()` then.  Otherwise clarify your question.

Comment: There's only one (sane) value of `NoneType`, which is `None`. The only result of that conversion can be `None` itself, so just use that value directly.

Comment: Also, `str(None) == 'None'` but to go backwards you have to use @Alok's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trivially define your own function to do this:

```
def none(*args):
    """Converts any arguments to None."""
    return None
```

But that's pretty pointless. Just use a literal `None` whenever you need one.

---

As for your clarification, what you're looking for is probably [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) or the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) module, though you should seriously consider what you're hoping to accomplish; `eval`, in particular, will create more problems for you than it is likely to solve.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove a variable then just delete it.

```
>>> a = 10
>>> print a
10
>>> del a
>>> print a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

If you want your variable to be None then just assign None to it.

```
>>> a = 10
>>> print a
10
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a = None
>>> print a
None
>>> type(a)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Hope this helps.